# How to pass complete model to stored procedure in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Is there any way to pass a complete model to stored procedure using C#?

We can pass parameters to stored procedure but I want to send complete model.

Comment: Is your model a hierarchy / graph of objects (e.g. aggregrate root), or is it simply a single object (`class Something`), or a collection of flat objects (`IEnumerable<Somethings>`)?

Comment: it simply flat object.

Comment: I can think of two options: 1. Table types and 2. User defined types (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131120%28SQL.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

See me answer to other question for complete code sample: [SqlBulkCopy Ignore Duplicate Records of Datatable From DataBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31340658/sqlbulkcopy-ignore-duplicate-records-of-datatable-from-database/31341551?noredirect=1#comment51029190_31341551)

Basically, you can pass a whole datatable. The Merge part is likely not relavent to you.

Comment: i don't want extra code to convert model to data table is any short way to to do this??

Comment: @Ahsan,  not sure how to achieve this without datatable.

Comment: just convert model type to datatable type in c#

Answer (score -1):

If you are using SQL Server 2008 or above you can use [Table Valued Parameters.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx)